# Removing the last part of a string which is always the same pattern

Tags: php, regex, string

I have an array containing string of regions in Canada that follows this syntax: "region (province)" or "region - other region - other region (province)". There can be any number of regions grouped together separated by " - " in a same string. I would like to trim the last space in each string, the parenthesis and the province name from those strings, making them in this format instead: "region" or "region - other region - other region".

How could I do this with a regex (or any other method) in PHP?

Comment: Alternatively str_replace() could work

Comment: Regarding the `"(province)"` string -- it's not clear where it may or may not appear and if it is or is not fixed.

Comment: $myStr = str_replace(" (province)", "", $myStr);

Comment: @Jon Just to answer your question to add some precision even though I have got the answer already: "(province)" is always there, but is not fixed. So it could be "(Alberta)" or "(manitoba)" for example.

Comment: The answer you've chosen will fail if there is more than one set of parenthesis in the string.

Comment: @sln Thanks for the notice. In my case though this won't be a problem. I voted your comment up so that people that see my question and it's answer will know about that.

Comment: @Choub890 - It really doesn't matter about your case, `.*` is a red flag and shouldn't be used in any regex unless it's meant to match backtracking from the end. So it is specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$string = array();
$string[] = "region - other region - other region (province)";
foreach ($string as $str){
    echo trim(preg_replace('/(\(.*\))$/','', $str));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a simple function like this?

```
function str_before($haystack,$needle)
// returns part of haystack string before the first occurrence of needle.
{
  $pos = strpos($haystack,$needle);
  return ($pos !== FALSE) ? substr($haystack,0,$pos) : $haystack;
}
```

And then use it this way:

```
$data = str_before($data,' (');
```

I often find that must easier to read than regex things, and you too, since you need to ask.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
$value = 'region - other region - other region (province)';

$result = substr($value, 0, strrpos( $value, ' '));

echo $result;
```

This would echo

```
region - other region - other region
```

Alternatively using a loop you could do the following:

```
$value = array('region - other region - other region (province)');

foreach($value as &$v)
{
    $v = substr($v, 0, strrpos( $v, ' '));
}

print_r($value);
```

Which would print this:

```
Array ( [0] => region - other region - other region )
```

Answer (score 1):

As [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) works on array, how about:

```
$array = preg_replace('/\s+\(.+$/', '', $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Run two regex on same string.
(run each as global replace and expanded)

1. This removes provinces'
   find:   `\( [^()]* \)`
   replace: `''`
2. This formats separator's
   find: `\h* - \h*`
   replace: `' - '`
3. Optional, can trim leading and trailing whitespace
   find: `^\s+|\s+$`
   replace: `''`